# Is it possible to create matter from space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, virtual-particles

Like could maybe fluctuate the space some how and make the virtual paricles turn into normal matter

Comment: "Space" is merely a mathematical concept that is used to write down equations of the vacuum. One can't make matter from a mathematical concept. One can, however, convert energy in the vacuum into matter. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't violate the conservation of energy (at least not on long timescales) so you can't just create matter from nothing. If you're going to create matter from energy then that energy has to come from somewhere.

One example of this is Hawking radiation. Although we often talk about a black hole event horizon as though it were an object, it is not. A black hole is entirely vacuum except for the singularity at the centre, so the particles that make up Hawking radiation are appearing from the vacuum. The energy to create the particles is coming from the spacetime curvature and ultimately from the black hole mass.

If you're looking at some some region of spacetime far from any black holes or other matter it's hard to see where the energy could come from. In principle you can have gravitational energy even in the absence of matter, for example gravitational waves or [geons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geon_(physics)) (the latter currently exist only in the fevered imaginations of theorists) and I suppose these could decay to create matter. Alternatively it has been suggested that what we see as the vacuum is actually a [false vacuum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum) that could decay to the true vacuum. This would create particles, though if the vacuum decayed we wouldn't be around to see them.

Comment: No offense, but it's a bit daring to say that a black hole is "entirely vacuum except for a singularity at the center", when we have never seen a black hole up-close and without a well tested theory of what a black hole really looks like at the quantum level. There are plenty of people who will disagree about the singularity, for sure, and I am not saying this to get into a discussion about it.

Comment: What about quantum fluctuations?

Comment: @KyleKanos: the only thing I know for sure is that quantum fluctuations are more complicated than I think. I believe the picture of particles and antiparticles popping into existance is an overliteral interpretation of the phenomenon, though there is an excellent chance I'm talking rubbish here. Anyhow, quantum fluctuations don't violate energy in long timescales.

Comment: "the latter currently exist only in the fevered imaginations of theorists" - so do the former, though of course they're much more widely accepted.

Comment: @Kyle: well no, for example we have [binary pulsar measurements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSR_B1913+16) that **strongly** suggest GWs are carrying away energy. And of course BICEP2 may still come out smelling of roses.

Answer (score 3):

In curved space, and even more so in expanding curved space, the concept of a vacuum wherein there are no particles has significant ambiguity. This is all covered very thoroughly in chapter 3 of "Quantum Fields in Curved Space" by Birrell and Davies. In normal flat space, we can define a vacuum state with no particles that every inertial observer would agree on, however in curved space this is not always possible. The reasoning behind this is very heavily mathematical, so it isn't for the faint of heart. I'll give a very short description of what happens, but I encourage those who are more interested to find and look through the book I mentioned.

In expanding curved space (like say at the beginning of inflation), we can choose a state that we might locally observe as the vacuum state (although there is still a but of ambiguity here). In the presence of a massive quantum field (any old quantum field will do, even the inflaton field) with out without perturbations/quantum fluctuations, what you find is that the mass of the quantum field couples the field to the expanding spacetime in the form of scalar perturbations in the field (and in the metric). As curved space expands, this effectively feeds energy into these perturbed scalar field modes. The end result of this is that what once you would have observed as a vacuum now must have particles in it. For a general curved space that is expanding, this mechanism usually makes any defined vacuum produce particles.

There are special cases (like Minkowski space) where particles are not spontaneously generated in the vacuum. This is why we don't see particles pop into existence all around us; locally our space greatly resembles Minkowski space. However, near a black hole or during inflation, particle production from quantum fluctuations of the vacuum state can occur.